# How to active app when app is in background at specific time in iphone?

Tags: iphone, background

At specific time, I want active app when it is in background? But I don't know. Actually, I am doing a alarm clock app, when on time, this app is displayed automatically.

Comment: Try google first then n then ask here dear.. n try to search on UILocalNotification for Alarm..

Answer (score 5):

it's not possible, what you can do is schedule a LocalNotification. When the notification is fired the user is prompt with the notification. Then the user can decide to open the app or ignore the notification.